# How to config the server to get access to mysql from external

Tags: linux, netbeans, debian

Hy!

I have a debian server with  a installed mysql server.

Now my problem is that i don't get access from external.

How to config it?

Hint: netbeans doesn't support ssh; i looked into the iptables and there is no change from stock

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want access to your debian server console from the outside through ssh, you have to install the ssh daemon on it:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install ssh
```